# Design Modular Web Wizards using .Net 2.0 Wizard Control

Tags: asp.net, refactoring, controls, wizard

We have about 10 applications that basically do the same thing, all written using the Wizard Control for .Net 2.0.  The flow they follow is pretty simple:

```
1. User selects option from a drop downs.
2. Next page has more options more narrowed.
3. User sees confirmation page.
4. Report is generated.
```

Some of these applications have optional pages, such as allowing the user to upload custom images for the report and allowing the user to select specific lines of data.

I'm attempting to merge these applications, but I'm not sure I'm approaching this the correct way.  My first inclination is to create configuration tables in SQL to drive the menus that appear.  So, for example, there might be a table with the `WizardId`, `Name`, `Theme`, etc., also a table of steps, and another table to link everything together.

Is there an easier way to approach this that I'm just missing?

Answer (score 0):

We've been thinking through this issue lately and I've come up with two options that both seem valid, just have different uses.  One way to do it, similar to what you have described, is to create the following:

- A table that holds the wizard information
- A table that lists the types of questions to be asked in each wizard
- A table to hold the data entered by the user for each question

This is very flexible, but the problem is you have to dynamically generate all the controls you need to collect the information (textbox, drop down, radio, file upload, etc) and store how to display that control in your database.

The other approach that we have tried out on a recent project is to associate a user control with either each wizard or type of wizard step.  It isn't as modular, but you have a lot of control over how the controls are arranged and how you collect the data.

I think both approaches are useful in different scenarios.  Going with a database driven approach allows you to generate new questions and wizards easily, but lacks the user friendly approach that we wanted for our new application.